# How to pass arguments to an Actor with WebSocket.withActor()

Tags: java, playframework, websocket, akka

```
// code in controller
LegacyWebSocket tt = WebSocket.withActor(ChatNode::props);
// ...


// chatnode actor code
public class ChatNode extends UntypedActor {

public static Props props(ActorRef out) {
    return Props.create(ChatNode.class, out);
}

private final ActorRef out;
private String username;

public ChatNode(ActorRef out, String username) {
    this.out = out;
    this.username = username;
}
```

This is the default way (according to Play docs) to handle websockets with actors. My question is:
How do I pass an argument to this newly created actor that is bound to a socket, i.e. I want to send from a controller some information as an argument to a constructor of ChatNode?

Answer (score 0):

You can use lambda for this, here is quick example:

```
public LegacyWebSocket<String> socket(String token) {
    return WebSocket.withActor(actorRef -> WSActor.props(actorRef,token));
}
```